# backgroundColor as switch function?

Tags: javascript

This code shows no errors but is not working, can anyone see why?

```
function setStyles(){
    var ya
    styles=document.getElementById("back");
    switch (ya){
        case 1:styles.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000';
            break;
        case 2:styles.style.backgroundColor='#FF6600';
            break;
        case 3:styles.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF66';
            break;
        case 4:styles.style.backgroundColor='#669900';
            break;
        case 5:styles.style.backgroundColor='#000066';
            break;
        case 6:styles.style.backgroundColor='#660066';
            break;
    }
}

window.onload = setStyles;
```

Comment: You haven't specified what `ya` is, or where it's from.

Comment: J. Steen's comment pretty much covers it, but for future questions it would be helpful to include an explanation of what your code is supposed to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the case statements will be matched because `ya` is undefined. Try defining it (in other words give it a value):

```
var ya = 1;
```

You could also define a `default` case which will be executed if none of the other case statements match:

```
...
...
case 6:
    styles.style.backgroundColor='#660066';
    break;
default:
    styles.style.backgroundColor='#000000';
...
```

Edit: to get a random background color:

```
var ya = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

Comment: it's supposed to randomly onload backgroundColor, so it changes every time....... just thought it'd be cool

Comment: see that doesn't do what I wanted can I put a math.Random in as the definition of ya?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you define ya:

```
function setStyles(ya){
  var ya;

  styles=document.getElementById("back");

  switch (ya) {
    case 1:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000';
    break;

    case 2:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#FF6600';
    break;

    case 3:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF66';
    break;

    case 4:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#669900';
    break;

    case 5:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#000066';
    break;

    case 6:
      styles.style.backgroundColor='#660066';
    break;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setStyles(1);
};
```

http://jsbin.com/agajen/1/edit